# AggregationContainer vs. AggregationDescriptor

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to send an array of ranges to an Aggregation Descriptor, but the Lambda expression expects a comma delimited expresions

> .Aggregations(agg =>
>               {
>                   AggregationDescriptor ag = agg.Terms("objectTypes", ot => ot.Field("doc.objectType"));
>
> ```
>             if (!parameters.ContainsKey("userID"))
>                 ag = ag.Terms("users", ot => ot.Field("doc.entryUserID"));//.Field("doc.sourceUserID")))
>             ag.Terms("commentTypes", ot => ot.Field("doc.commentType"));
>
>             if (!parameters.ContainsKey("dateRange"))
>             {
>                 Dictionary<string, SearchDateRange> dateMap = GetDateRangeMap();
>
>                 ag.DateRange("dates", dr => dr.Field("doc.date").Format("yyyy-MM-dd")
>                     .Ranges(r1 => r1.Key("Today").From(dateMap["Today"].startDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")).To("now"),
>                             r2 => r2.Key("SinceWednesday").From(dateMap["Today"].startDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")).To("now"),
>                             r3 => r3.Key("ThisYear").From(dateMap["ThisYear"].startDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")).To("now"),
>                             r3 => r3.Key("Last2Years").From(dateMap["Last2Years"].startDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")).To("now"),
>                             r4 => r4.Key("Last3Years").From(dateMap["Last3Years"].startDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")).To("now")
>                             ));
>
>             }
> ```

The above code works.

Below I would like to use the Range[] array and pass it to the aggregate discriptor but I can't, but I can create an AggregationContainer with the range array. How do I marry these two pieces together?

> ```
>             if (!parameters.ContainsKey("revenueRange") && docTypes.Contains(CouchbaseDocumentType.Company))
>             {
>                 Dictionary<string, SearchNumberRange> numMap = GetMoneyRangeMap();
>                 Range<double>[] ranges = numMap.Select(m =>
>                 {
>                     var r = new Range<double>().Key(m.Key);
>                     if (m.Value.low.HasValue) r.From(m.Value.low.Value);
>                     if (m.Value.high.HasValue) r.To(m.Value.high.Value);
>                     return r;
>                 }).ToArray();
>
>                 AggregationContainer agr = new AggregationContainer
>                 {
>                     Range = new RangeAggregator { Field = "doc.lastFinancial.revenueUSD", Ranges = ranges }
>                 };
>
>             }
>
>             return ag;
>         }
>         )
> ```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created simple example to show you how you can achieve this.

```
var funcs = new List<Func<Range<double>, Range<double>>>();

funcs.Add(range => new Range<double>().From(1).To(2));
funcs.Add(range => new Range<double>().From(3).To(4));

var searchResponse = client.Search<Document>(
    s => s.Aggregations(agg => agg.Range("range", descriptor => descriptor.Field(f => f.Number).Ranges(funcs.ToArray()))));
```

Document class:

```
public class Document
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double Number { get; set; }
}
```

Hope you won't have problem with putting it into your context.